# нужно написать скрипт для замены флага и сокращенного названия языка при его выборе

Tags: html, jquery

Всем привет!
Есть вот такой дропдаун https://prnt.sc/gbzgx3

И код:

```css
.dropdown_lang .bdd_lang {
  background: inherit;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  padding: 4px 12px; }
  .dropdown_lang .bdd_lang:hover, .dropdown_lang .bdd_lang:focus {
    background: inherit; }
  .dropdown_lang .bdd_lang span {
    font-family: PFSquareSansPro-Regular;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #a6aaae;
    margin-left: 9px; }
  .dropdown_lang .bdd_lang img {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2); }

.dropdown_lang .dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #434a54;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  padding: 0;
  left: -58px;
  top: 45px;
  box-shadow: none; }
  .dropdown_lang .dropdown-menu:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    right: 20px;
    top: -20px;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #434a54; }
  .dropdown_lang .dropdown-menu li {
    height: auto; }
    .dropdown_lang .dropdown-menu li a {
      font-family: PFSquareSansPro-Regular;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 40px; }
      .dropdown_lang .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
        background-color: #393f48;
        background-image: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="dropdown dropdown_lang">
                            <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle bdd_lang" type="button" id="dropdown_lang" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                <img src="img/icons/if_RU_167813.png" alt="">
                                <span>RU</span>
                                <span class="caret"></span>
                            </button>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                                <li><a href="#">Українська</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Руский</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

нужно написать скрипт для замены флага и сокращенного названия языка при его выборе. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Помощь в виде написания кода за вас?

Comment: а для чего? тыкаете по языку, дальше выдаете страницу с другим языком. Я сомневаюсь что у вас на лету контент меняется)